# Create two Aliases from same column, but give them different values based on content

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create two aliases in SQL, but based on the content of the column, I want to assign the aliases different values.

Let's say I have a column containing a quantity value, but I want to sort the ones that have a value higher than 10, and lower than 10 into different aliases.

```
Select Quantity as Higher
    , Quantity as Lower
From Table

Higher                       |    Lower
*All values higher than 10   |   *All values lower than 10*
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this I think (the precise syntax may be dependent on your DBMS product, which you didn't mention):

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN quantity >= 10 THEN quantity ELSE NULL END AS Higher,
CASE WHEN quantity < 10 THEN quantity ELSE NULL END AS Lower
FROM yourtable
```

You also didn't supply exact expected results, so if you want something different you'll have to clarify the question. Thanks.

Comment: That syntax is ANSI SQL, and _should_ work on all products.

Comment: @jarlh Indeed, I'd hope so, but there's always a slight chance of it being some obscure product which mangles the syntax. And the remark was partly a prompt to OP that it might be a good idea to mention the DBMS in future :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked! 
Will remember DBMS next time, first ever post here so.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what you're asking for, but at a complete guess, are you looking for something like this...?

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN quantity >= 10 THEN quantity ELSE NULL END AS "10 or Higher",
  CASE WHEN quantity < 10 THEN quantity ELSE NULL END AS "Lower than 10"
FROM mytable
```

Comment: Those square brackets are product specific, and the question has no dbms specified. I'd use ANSI SQL compliant double quotes instead, e.g. `"Lower than 10"`. (BTW, doesn't SQL Server accept those as well?)

Comment: Fair comments... yes, SQLServer does accept double-quotes